# Android: BluetoothGattCallback returns connection is congested

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have an issue with the current 2019 Samsung Galaxy devices (S10). I can make a write to a Bluetooth Characteristic once. Then, if I try the call again, the `onConnectionStateChange` override method returns a status of "8". According to Google this means [GATT_CONNECTION_CONGESTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#GATT_CONNECTION_CONGESTED). I can validate the first call works too. Also, soon after the congested errors returns, the phone disconnects from the app.

After pulling Samsung's bluetooth logs using `adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager`, I can see this error:

> BluetoothRemoteDevices -- ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED, device is 30AEA4,
>   reason is 8, linktype is 2

Weirdly, I can use just about any other Android device, Pixel, Essential, older Samsungs, and not one of them returns this error message after a second call and work as expected. All of the current line of Samsung Galaxy devices all seems throw this error. Does anyone know what this error message means exactly and how to avoid it?